# How to find a directory containing a file with one extension and not containing a file with another extension in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have to filter out a huge number directories/paths, that contain files with the extension .spring (a compressed file of two fastq files). But in some of these directories, .fastq.gz files are still present. I need to get the path of those directories where there is only .spring files and not .fastq.gz files. (Specifically I need to get the path of those .spring files).

I have tried using the find command, but somehow it is not working as I intended.
Please give some suggestions

Also how do I check if the directory contains both the files - .fastq.gz and .spring?

Thanks

I tried the following:

```
find $(find $PWD -name "*.spring" -printf '%h\\n') -not -name  "*.fastq.gz"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bash script that returns the desired list:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

# find all directories containing *.spring files
spring_dirs=$(find $PWD -type f -name '*.spring' -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u)

# within the directories containing *.spring files,
# find those directories that also contain *.fastq.gz files,
# but use -maxdepth 1 to not look any deeper than the *.spring file dir
fastq_dirs=$(find $spring_dirs -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.fastq.gz' -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u)

# concatenate the two sets of directories and only keep the ones
# that are not repeated
spring_only_dirs=$(printf "%s\n%s\n" "$spring_dirs" "$fastq_dirs" | sort | uniq -u)

# use the directories of *.spring files to get the full
# file names of the *.spring files
find $spring_only_dirs -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.spring'
```

This is not the fastest approach, but hopefully easy to understand and fairly short. As noted in the comments, this approach will fail if there are spaces (or new lines) in the file names or paths. While it is possible to deal with file names containing whitespace in bash, it would make the script significantly longer and more complex.

Here is a more robust implementation in python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from os import walk
from pathlib import Path

MUST_CONTAIN_GLOB = '*.spring'
NOT_CONTAIN_GLOB = '*.fastq.gz'
out_files = [str(f)
             for root, _, _ in walk(".")
             for f in Path(root).glob(MUST_CONTAIN_GLOB)
             if not list(Path(root).glob(NOT_CONTAIN_GLOB))]
print("\n".join(out_files))
```

Comment: Don't know whether it is relevant to the OP, but this approach would fail if there are files containing spaces in their names.

Comment: You are correct @user1934428. I have added a Python implementation that works with whitespace in file names.

Comment: You could speed this up by providing a predicate that allows you to do all of the matching in one function, so you only do the file globbing once. Example in perl from the book "Higher Order Perl" , ... the function dir_walk.

Comment: I have updated the python script to use os.walk() so that it only walks the directory structure once as suggested by @ScottHoffman.